# Mongodb get data using ISO format date

Tags: mongodb

I am saving data into mongodb and the dates are in this format for instance

`7/30/1960 (july 30, 1960)` is `ISODate("1960-07-30T05:00:00.000+0000")`,

I want to find records created today(and i dont care about the time,so long as its today) and i have this

```
var start = new Date();
var end = new Date();
```

and to display the data

```
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```

Will this work or must i convert my iso dates to another format first?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the 'start' and 'end' variables before querying:

```
var start = new Date();
start.setHours(0,0,0,0); // remove time part from the date

var end = new Date();
end.setHours(0,0,0,0); // remove time
end.setDate(end.getDate() + 1); // add a day to the end date
```

and then you can use your query:

```
db.posts.find({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});
```